# How to define side for all obs of same name within the same ID group?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data set:

```
BigID      MedID    LittleID    Name     CenterY       Y
958         115         A       Joe       1.5          2
958         115         A       Eric      1.5          1.2
958         115         A       Mike      1.5          3
958         116         B       Joe       1.5          3.3
958         116         B       Eric      1.5          2.5
958         116         B       Mike      1.5          4.9
959         180         A       Joe       2.3          3.1
959         180         A       Eric      2.3          6.8
959         180         A       Mike      2.3          4.1
```

I am looking to create a new column which indicates if Y is greater than CenterY when LittleID is equal to "A". If "y" is greater than "CenterY" I want the  new column to read "left", if it is smaller I want it to read "right," if is the same I want it to read "center".

The important thing is I want the new column to reflect if Y is greater than Y at A for all the values of MedID for each 'Name'. So the above table would become:

```
BigID      MedID    LittleID    Name     CenterY       Y       Side
958         115         A       Joe       1.5          2       Left
958         115         A       Eric      1.5          1.2     Right
958         115         A       Mike      1.5          3       Left
958         116         B       Joe       1.5          3.3     Left
958         116         B       Eric      1.5          2.5     Right
958         116         B       Mike      1.5          4.9     Left
959         180         A       Joe       2.3          3.1     Left
959         180         A       Eric      2.3          6.8     Left
959         180         A       Mike      2.3          4.1     Left
```

As you can see, for all values of LittleID within BigId/MedId, Eric has the value 'Left' for 'Side' because his Y is greater than center y at A.

How can I accomplish this in R? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Side = case_when(LittleID == 'A' & Y >= CenterY ~ 'Left', 
           LittleID == 'A' & Y < CenterY ~ 'Right', 
            LittleID == 'A' & Y == CenterY ~ 'Center')) %>% 
    group_by(BigID) %>%
    mutate(Side = replace(Side, LittleID == 'B', Side[LittleID == 'A'])) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 9 x 7
#  BigID MedID LittleID Name  CenterY     Y Side 
#  <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1   958   115 A        Joe       1.5   2   Left 
#2   958   115 A        Eric      1.5   1.2 Right
#3   958   115 A        Mike      1.5   3   Left 
#4   958   116 B        Joe       1.5   3.3 Left 
#5   958   116 B        Eric      1.5   2.5 Right
#6   958   116 B        Mike      1.5   4.9 Left 
#7   959   180 A        Joe       2.3   3.1 Left 
#8   959   180 A        Eric      2.3   6.8 Left 
#9   959   180 A        Mike      2.3   4.1 Left
```

---

Or another option is to first `filter` the rows where 'LittleID' is "A", then create the 'Side' column with `sign`, do a join with the original data and `replace` the values others than the 'A' with the same values of 'Side' from the 'A' LittleID

```
df1 %>% 
    filter(LittleID == "A") %>% 
    mutate(Side = setNames(c("Right", "Center", "Left"), 
        c(-1, 0, 1))[as.character(sign(Y - CenterY))]) %>%   
    right_join(df1) %>%
    group_by(BigID) %>% 
    mutate(Side = replace(Side, LittleID == 'B', Side[LittleID == 'A'])) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(BigID = c(958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 
959L, 959L, 959L), MedID = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
180L, 180L, 180L), LittleID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A"), Name = c("Joe", "Eric", "Mike", "Joe", "Eric", 
"Mike", "Joe", "Eric", "Mike"), CenterY = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3), Y = c(2, 1.2, 3, 3.3, 2.5, 4.9, 3.1, 
6.8, 4.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```